# Sharepoint web part stops working because of Resources.en-US.resx file

Tags: sharepoint, web-parts, resx

I've been developing a Sharepoint web part, which had been working fine upon deployment.  The web part has been developed with WSP Builder, packaged up and then deployed via stsadm.  The web part has been deployed tens, if not a hundred times to the dev box with no problems.  Now, the web part throws an error which breaks the page it's on:

> Object reference not set to an
>   instance of an object.  Description:
>   An unhandled exception occurred during
>   the execution of the current web
>   request. Please review the stack trace
>   for more information about the error
>   and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details:
>   System.NullReferenceException: Object
>   reference not set to an instance of an
>   object.
>
> Source Error:
>
> An unhandled exception was generated
>   during the execution of the current
>   web request. Information regarding the
>   origin and location of the exception
>   can be identified using the exception
>   stack trace below.
>
> Stack Trace:
>
> [NullReferenceException: Object
>   reference not set to an instance of an
>   object.]
>   NYCIRB.DMS.WebParts.SearchUpload.SearchUpload.HandleException(Exception
>   ex) +62
>   NYCIRB.DMS.WebParts.SearchUpload.SearchUpload.OnLoad(EventArgs
>   e) +214
>   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()
>   +50    System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()
>   +141    System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()
>   +141    System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()
>   +141    System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()
>   +141    System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()
>   +141    System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean
>   includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean
>   includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +627

When looking through my Sharepoint logs, I find these errors repeated over and over which correspond to the time the web part was attempted to be loaded:

> 01/19/2009 10:53:14.43    w3wp.exe
>   (0x05E0)
>     0x00FC  Windows SharePoint Services
>     General
>     72kg    High        (#2: Cannot open
>   "Resources.en-US.resx": no such file
>   or folder.)     01/19/2009 10:53:14.43
>     w3wp.exe (0x05E0)
>     0x00FC  Windows SharePoint Services
>     General
>     8e26    Medium      Failed to open the
>   language resource for
>   Fea367b94a9-4a15-42ba-b4a2-32420363e018
>   keyfile Resources. 01/19/2009
>   10:53:17.55   w3wp.exe (0x05E0)
>     0x00FC  Windows SharePoint Services
>     General
>     8e25    Medium      Failed to look up
>   string with key "XomlUrl", keyfile
>   core.   01/19/2009 10:53:17.55
>     w3wp.exe (0x05E0)
>     0x00FC  Windows SharePoint Services
>     General
>     8l3c    Medium      Localized resource for
>   token 'XomlUrl' could not be found for
>   file with path: "C:\Program
>   Files\Common Files\Microsoft
>   Shared\Web Server
>   Extensions\12\Template\Features\Fields\fieldswss.xml".
>   01/19/2009 10:53:17.55    w3wp.exe
>   (0x05E0)
>     0x00FC  Windows SharePoint Services
>     General
>     8e25    Medium      Failed to look up
>   string with key "RulesUrl", keyfile
>   core.   01/19/2009 10:53:17.55
>     w3wp.exe (0x05E0)
>     0x00FC  Windows SharePoint Services
>     General
>     8l3c    Medium      Localized resource for
>   token 'RulesUrl' could not be found
>   for file with path: "C:\Program
>   Files\Common Files\Microsoft
>   Shared\Web Server
>   Extensions\12\Template\Features\Fields\fieldswss.xml".

I've retracted the web part manually through Solution Management, retracted through stsadm, checked for the existence of the resource file, which is nowhere to be found.  I'm pretty much at a loss to why this happened or how to resolve it.

Answer (score 1):

try to meke sure that all your resource files contain all rows. In classic aspx if you have resources.resx and resources.en-us.resx and the second doesn't contain some entry, framework automatically looks into default file and serves default translation. It doesn't work like this in MOSS sadly.